# Javascript Logical Operator && used to Assign Properties

Tags: javascript, operators, logical-operators

I encountered this piece of code:

```
var value = this.newTodo && this.newTodo.trim();
```

In this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rONEMQ?editors=101

I don't understand what the **AND** (***&&***) operator is trying to accomplish.

In my understanding the **&&** Operator is to asign multiple properties to a value, but this doesn't seem to be the case here.

I my code example, I don't see any difference, for when I use this:

```
var value = this.newTodo && this.newTodo.trim();
```

Instead of this:

```
var value = this.newTodo;
```

Or just this:

```
var value = this.newTodo.trim();
```

Can anyone explain, what the initial line stated above and in the example does with the **&&**?

Comment: `var value = this.newTodo && this.newTodo.trim();` roghly  is that if `this.newTodo` is `truthy` then assign `this.newTodo.trim()` to `value` variable

Comment: If `this.newTodo` does not evaluate to `True` then `this.newTodo.trim()` won't ever be called. If it does evaluate to True then it will be trimmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value = this.newTodo && this.newTodo.trim();
```

if this.newTodo is not one of "falsey" values, i.e. `""`, `0`, `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `[]` (I'm sure I'm forgetting some), then `value = this.newTodo.trim()`, otherwise `value = this.newTodo` (which could be `""`, `0`, `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `[]` etc)

> I my code example, I don't see any difference, for when I use this:
>
> var value = this.newTodo && this.newTodo.trim();
>
> Instead of this:
>
> var value = this.newTodo;

if this.newTodo is `"Hello World"` ... you're right, there is no difference

if this.newTodo id `" Hello World "` ... value will be `"Hello World"` ... i.e. **trim**med of leading and trailing spaces

Comment: So it could be written like this: var value = if (this.newTodo == false) { return this.newTodo; } else { return this.newTodo.trim(); }